# Streaming large XML datasets with Spring WebFlux

Tags: json, xml, spring, reactive

The steps to stream arbitrarily large json document streams using Spring WebFlux are detailed in this very informative blog:

https://kamilszymanski.github.io/serving-large-datasets-with-spring-webflux/

This shows how to flush a json document at a time to the receiving client in a reactive manner.

How can this be achieved in WebFlux using XML documents? So given a stream of XML documents how does one flush an XML document at a time to the Http client?

Comment: Why would it be different...

Comment: The trick to getting the json to stream was to use the mime type: application/stream+json. Is there an equivalent for XML?

Comment: The problem with XML is is that you would need en enclosing type. You cannot return a list of XML types as you can with JSON. What you can try is to create another implementation of the `AbstractJackson2Encoder` for XML (Jackson can also serialize/deserialize XML) and see if you can get it to work. I'm however afraid that out-of-the-box it won't work due to the nature of XML.